# One table for all, or seperated user tables for multiple roles

Tags: laravel, authentication, multi-user

i am trying to make a school management web site. But i can't decide yet that user tables seperated for students, parents, teachers, management etc. Or one user table for all with role. (relation with seperated profile table) . What do you prefer?

I tried one user table for all. But its is so complicated future. And the tried seperated user table. But the structure and the laravel settings are so complicated for me. I need simple solution for now and future.

Comment: Users should be the people that can login and use your system, stored in their own Table. Roles are useful for determining what Users can access, and should also be in their own Table, linked to Users via a `role_id` (if you only allow 1 Role), or a `pivot` table (if you allow multiple Roles). Parents, Teachers and Students sound like they should be separate entities, but you can link them back to a User, via a `student_id` (or inverse, `user_id`) on the respective table. There isn't a "1 size fits all" solution for this; you need to figure out how to structure your data and implement it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Tim Lewis mentionned in his comment, the user table should be for user who can login to your site. They can have roles like (Superadmin, admin, editor...)
Then you could have tables for each type of persons (students, parents, teachers, ...) with specific columns and relations between each.
If some types of persons should be able to login then create a user associated to a profile (student, parent...).